# CSS not working with CakePHP App

Tags: cakephp

I'm having a problem with CakePHP, the CSS is not found. When I view the source code in my browser I can see the cake generic CSS link in the head section. But when I click on it to see the actual source code, I get a 404 not found error.

**Update:** 
I've followed the instructions here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

to make sure the mod_rewrite is setup correctly but I'm still having trouble viewing the CSS file.

**Update:**
THis is what .htaccess looks like in my root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what .htaccess looks like in my app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and this is what it looks like in my webroot folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Are the permissions for that file correct?

Comment: Is the file in the directory you think it's in?

Comment: @MrSlayer yes, they are correct.

Comment: @DiMono yes, its in the correct directory.

Comment: You might have a problem with mode rewrite or the `.htaccess` file. Are you using Apache?

Comment: This is very much not enough information to guess what could be the problem. Take a look at the questions in the "related" pane -->  any of them work?

Comment: sounds like a url rewriting error

Comment: @steve yes, I'm using apache on my Mac Book Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. The problem was with the way I set up my virtual host, my httpd-vhosts.conf file now looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@invoice.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/stephenxconnolly/Documents/Websites/invoice-new"
    ServerName invoice.dev
    <Directory "/Users/stephenxconnolly/Documents/Websites/invoice-new/">
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
#   ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/invoice.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/invoice.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you letting CakePHP create the link to the CSS? Like this:

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

If Apache is pointing at webroot, and your CSS is in webroot/css/cake.generic.css, then you should be able to browse it at

```
http://website/css/cake.generic.css
```

If you put the CSS file in webroot can you browse it ok?

Comment: In answer to your first questions, yes I'm letting CakePHP create the link to the CSS file as you've shown above. I can't browse the cake.generic.css I get No Data Received error message.

Comment: Can you see the file on disk (in Finder), what directory is it in? Did you try moving it to webroot and link to it manually (not using CakePHP's helper)?

Comment: @tobi1kenobi Yes, I can see the file in Finder projectname/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css  I'm not sure what you mean by move it to webroot, when CakePHP is installed, this is the default location for the file.

Comment: yes, location looks good, I just wondered if you linked to it in webroot and it worked this might give you some clue as to what's happening (like permissions on your css folder or something).