# My CSS files are not loading due to a 404 error in CakePHP. Why is this?

Tags: cakephp

I just uploaded a brand new copy of CakePHP 2.3 into a new domain-name, and right away it says "GET http://example.com/css/cake.generic.css 404 (Not Found)" in chrome. I don't understand why it is doing this. I have made other CakePHP websites and had this problem but I remember solving it accidentally, not knowing what I did. I would like to know exactly how to solve this problem, if anyone knows.

There is info out there about htaccess, mod_rewrite, and other things I don't understand. I don't know anything about where these files are, what they do, how to use them, etc.

Please help!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey there; is there any way you could post part of your HTML output?  (At least the part where you are trying to include your CSS files...)

Comment: It's completely just the standard layout file and just the front page which is controller=>pages action=>display, home.

Comment: The only change I made in the entire app was the cipher seed and salt in app/config/core

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css"> Sorry 3 comments in a row

Comment: Hmm, what does your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`  `RewriteEngine on`  
    `RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]`  
    `RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]`  
`</IfModule>`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant... could that be added to your original question? :)

Comment: Something might be going on with your server settings, as well; if you have the authority to change settings in your server (or wherever you are hosting this app... maybe just on your own computer or wherever,) you might want to try looking into the [`AllowOverride` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) that could potentially allow you to use your `.htaccess` files as you wish.  It's not necessarily the best way to go about things, but it can work.

Comment: Also, here is another [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788264/css-not-working-with-cakephp-app) where someone had a possibly similar situation going on... in cases like this, it often comes down to "allowing" `.htaccess` files to be read and used... hope that helps a little, though!

Comment: That does help thanks, but I'm having trouble finding the httpd conf file (whatever that is). I'm using dreamhost...

Comment: I can work on other websites for now...thanks for your help. For some reason, sometimes it works the first time, sometimes it takes some tinkering and I solve it accidentally and now it's just not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...I had to create my own .htaccess file in the root folder. CakePHP only comes with 2 .htaccess files...one in the webroot and one in the /app folder but you also need one in the root folder. I found the answer from this question. [.htaccess for cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp)

Comment: Incorrect, the default CakePHP package has 3 .htaccess files, you just missed copying one of them to your server. [1](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.htaccess) [2](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/.htaccess) [3](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/.htaccess)

Comment: If you say so...I just downloaded it straight from the website and made no changes to it and drag and dropped it to my server. Very strange.

Comment: It's not like I am making it up. Check the 1,2,3 links i have given in my previous comment to each .htaccess file which is included in the package. Many environments (most unix based systems) hide files starting with dot, that's why you must have missed the file on package root.

Comment: "I had to <make sure I didn't miss copying [this file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.htaccess) when uploading my site>"

Comment: Glad to hear that you found an answer!

Comment: CakePHP has only one `.htaccess` file inside webroot directory. No need more `.htaccess` files. You must set `app/webroot` as your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.